# How to get current target Name for webservice listener in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I"m using Alducente's webservice package to access a bunch of different webservice links for an online game, and would like to use a single "connected" listener rather than having a bunch of listeners for each of the connections.

However I'm having trouble trying to get the currentTarget's name in the listener, so as to proceed according to which service was connected.

---my code as follows---

```
import alducente.services.WebService;
import flash.events.*;

var serviceA:WebService = new WebService();
var serviceB:WebService = new WebService();

serviceA.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectedListener);
serviceB.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectedListener);

serviceA.connect("http://thatWebService.com/gameStuff.asmx?WSDL");  
serviceB.connect("http://thatWebService.com/accountStuff.asmx?WSDL");   


function  connectedListener(evt:Event):void{
    trace(evt.currentTarget);   //[object webservice]
    trace(evt.currentTarget.name);   //this gives undefined 

    //Do something if serviceA is connected
    //Do something else if serviceB is connected


}
```

Much thanks for your help!

Comment: That's not your code though is it? Your connected function will never be called in the example you've posted. Could you fix your example?

Comment: Are you even setting the name properties anywhere? doesn't look like it from your code.

Comment: What are expecting to do with the name value?

Comment: Fixed my code, thanks!  I was under the wrong impression that the name would be the name of the variable "serviceA", thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service won't have a name unless you give it one. `WebService` is a dynamic class so you should be able to do the following:

```
import alducente.services.WebService;
import flash.events.*;

var serviceA:WebService = new WebService();
serviceA.name = "serviceA";

var serviceB:WebService = new WebService();
serviceB.name = "serviceB";

serviceA.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connected);
serviceB.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connected);

serviceA.connect("http://thatWebService.com/gameStuff.asmx?WSDL");  
serviceB.connect("http://thatWebService.com/accountStuff.asmx?WSDL");   


function connected(evt:Event):void{
    trace(evt.currentTarget.name);   // should get the results now 
}
```